# Исключения из перебора бит по шаблону

Tags: c++

Вдохновленный этим вопросом [Bit hack to generate all integers with a given number of 1s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281951/bit-hack-to-generate-all-integers-with-a-given-number-of-1s) интересует, а возможно ли пропускать в генерации значений содержащих определенный шаблон?
К примеру, есть последовательность из 50 бит, 20 из которых 1:
`0b10000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111`
(1 бит в начале и 19 в конце).

Как создать такую генерацию, чтобы не было больше чем `6` идущих подряд 1-бит, и не больше чем `10` 0-бит? В любом распложении шаблона.

Тогда первое нужное число в данном примере будет:
`0b10000000010000000000100000000001111101111110111111`

а последнее `0b11111101111110111111011000000000000000000000000000`

Именно что не сортировка после всего перебора, а на лету.